# How can I sign a Gadget for Windows Sidebar?

Tags: certificate, windows-desktop-gadgets, signtool

Does anyone know how to sign a gadget for Windows Sidebar (*.gadget)?
I tried with signtool, but without any result.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need cabarc (from the Microsoft CAB SDK) and signtool (from the Windows 6 SDK). You can *not* sign ZIP gadget archives.

Follow the "Deploying" section at http://www.codeproject.com/kb/gadgets/gadgettips.aspx. I use the 'signtool signwizard' most of the time. You should already have an applicable code-signing certification (.cer) loaded into your certificate store.

Make sure you specify a time-server or your application will rejected from the Microsoft Gadget Gallery.

Comment: +1. I created a gadget that automated this process for me a few years ago.  When I moved over to working with Visual Studio, I wrote a build task to do it for me.  Remember that your certificate must also chain to a valid certification authority, otherwise it will be rejected.